# Single line if statement with 2 actions

Tags: c#, if-statement, action

I'd like to do a single line if statement with more than 1 action.

Default is this:

```
(if) ? then : else

userType = (user.Type == 0) ? "Admin" : "User";
```

But I don't need an "else" only, I need an "else if"

like that in multi line:

```
if (user.Type == 0)
    userType = "Admin" 
else if (user.Type == 1)
    userType = "User"
else if (user.Type == 2)
    userType = "Employee"
```

Is there a possibility for that in single line?

Comment: I think this might be a case where `enum` is better, if some of your APIs use integers, and others use strings, there might be update anomolies if you forget to update what each coupling means.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Sounds like you really want a `Dictionary<int, string>` or possibly a `switch` statement...

You *can* do it with the conditional operator though:

```
userType = user.Type == 0 ? "Admin"
         : user.Type == 1 ? "User"
         : user.Type == 2 ? "Employee"
         : "The default you didn't specify";
```

While you *could* put that in one line, I'd strongly urge you not to.

I would normally *only* do this for different conditions though - not just several different possible values, which is better handled in a map.

Comment: Jon, that's a bit too much I believe... Why complicating it further? (By the way, I'm glad to see you passing by the same question as me :)

Comment: @H2CO3: Which version are you saying is more complicated? We want to map an integer to a string - a dictionary seems like the most natural approach to me.

Comment: I mean the dictionary. I feel that it's rather the "good practice" that caught you here. Of course, you can use a dictionary - but hey, you could use an array the indices being the type of the user (which really should be consecutive integers, probably an enum), and for 3 poor simple integer, the ternary operator is not that bad! Personally I don't feel it to be unreadable at all. The switch statement is obviously better (from my point of view), if you consider `?:` unreadable, I'd rather suggest using `switch`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's basically the same like H2CO3's Answer, just better formatted

Comment: @user1676094: Yes, an array would be fine if the values really naturally start at 0 and are contiguous. The reason I don't like using the conditional operator here is that it makes the repeated use of `user.Type` seem coincidental - whereas really we're saying, "We've got one value - what does that value mean?" We really are trying to *map* integer values to strings - so why not use that? I'm fine with the conditional operator when it represents separate conditions, but this situation doesn't feel like that to me.

Comment: @Jon Skeet that's why I recommended the switch instead.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thanks for your comment. The reason why I wanted this in a single line, is because it's used as an argument in a String.Format. So that I can see in one line what it's doing.
But your comment makes sense, the repeating use of user.Type is not that good, so I will create an integer for that.

Answer (score 28):

```
userType = (user.Type == 0) ? "Admin" : (user.type == 1) ? "User" : "Admin";
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

You *can* write that in single line, but it's not something that someone would be able to read. Keep it like you already wrote it, it's already beautiful by itself.

If you have too much `if/else` constructs, you may think about using of different datastructures, like `Dictionaries` (to look up keys) or `Collection` (to run conditional `LINQ` queries on it)