# One liner if calling an action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement

I am trying to make the following if statement a oneliner. I looked at some articles([One-liner if statements, how to convert this if-else-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622600/one-liner-if-statements-how-to-convert-this-if-else-statement), [Single line if statement with 2 actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484133/single-line-if-statement-with-2-actions)), but the if statement in those is supposed to return a value. none of them calls a method. Any solutions?

```
StringBuilder Parameters = new StringBuilder();
if(Parameters.Length == 0)
{
    Parameters.Append("?");
}
    else
{
    Parameters.Append("&");
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would work:

```
Parameters.Append(Parameters.Length == 0 ? "?" : "&");
```

**Further Reading**

- [`?:` Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)